# storing dc.js filters in URI and restoring them

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

Here i selected 3 filters 1 from each chart and pasted that encoded url in url param. but when i press decode url button it is redrawing only middle chart filters but not the remaining once.. what should i do?
thanks

```
function encodeFunction()
{
    var filters = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < dc.chartRegistry.list().length; i++)
    {

        var chart = dc.chartRegistry.list()[i];

        for (var j = 0; j < chart.filters().length; j++)
        {
            filters.push({ChartID: chart.chartID(), Filter: chart.filters()[j]});
        }
    }
    var urlParam =  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filters));
    alert(urlParam);
}
function decodeFunction()
{
    //encoded url here
    var urlParam="%5B%7B%22ChartID%22%3A1%2C%22Filter%22%3A2012%7D%2C%7B%22ChartID%22%3A2%2C%22Filter%22%3A%5B1.0454545454545454%2C4.045454545454545%5D%7D%2C%7B%22ChartID%22%3A3%2C%22Filter%22%3A%22Mr%20B%22%7D%5D ";

    var filterObjects = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(urlParam));

    for (var i = 0; i< filterObjects.length; i++)
    {
        dc.chartRegistry.list()[filterObjects[i].ChartID-1].filter(filterObjects[i].Filter);
    }

    // dc.renderAll();

    dc.redrawAll();
}
```

here is the fiddle: [js fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/sandyn9062/31fswo3w/)

Comment: I'm no expert at dc.js, but you might get more people willing to answer if you ran your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ and only supplied the code relevant to your problem. If there's an error being thrown, perhaps a stacktrace would be helpful as well. This seems like a vague problem to me, and would be a much better question if you could at least narrow down what your problem is.

Comment: I agree with @PatrickRoberts. The better/more polite way to a ask this kind of question is to put your code in a jsFiddle so that people can try it out. Then post only the relevant parts in your SO question. Will upvote back to zero if you edit. :-) It's an interesting problem btw. We'd like to have a canonical way to store filters in an URL.

Comment: fixed your formatting and added a code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your code is correct for the general case, but due to some quirks in the way that dc.js handles filters, you can't just restore a range filter from its serialized form.

I was able to get it working by adding a special case for arrays:

```
   for (var i = 0; i< filterObjects.length; i++)
   {
       var filter = filterObjects[i].Filter;
       if(filter instanceof Array) filter = dc.filters.RangedFilter(filter[0], filter[1]);
       dc.chartRegistry.list()[filterObjects[i].ChartID-1].filter(filter);
   }
```

Here is my fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/4dv93aht/10/

I don't think such special cases should be needed, so I opened an issue here: https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/819

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer... only so I can better keep track of the tag, of course.  ;-)

Comment: yeah it worked for me...@Gordon . thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question & working example
[dc.js permalink or href to share the visualisation filter state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853794/dc-js-permalink-or-href-to-share-the-visualisation-filter-state)

https://github.com/Edouard-Legoupil/3W-Dashboard/blob/gh-pages/index.html

Comment: I like this approach better because it explicitly fetches the filters and applies them by name, rather than by index - although the code in the question is good for a quick and dirty solution. Thanks for sharing, I will be sure to use this when I document how to do this. For now this question can serve as informal docs.