# How to export graphs from a dc.js/bootstrap dashboard

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have created a data visualization dashboard using d3, dc, crossfilter and bootstrap. (much like the tutorial on github but without the leaflet)

I want to add an export function so that the user can select which charts to export. The result should be the chosen graphs plus a list of the **filters** applied.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8fe1acvr/

Comment: Serializing the filters is covered in this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853794/dc-js-permalink-or-href-to-share-the-visualisation-filter-state and an edge case is covered in this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675327/storing-dc-js-filters-in-uri-and-restoring-them. According to [this issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/684), SVG Crowbar works for exporting the SVGs.